# Setup webcaster (webcast.js) with liquidsoap and icecast

Tags: javascript, icecast, web-audio-api, liquidsoap

I'm testing [Webcast.js](https://webcast.github.io/) using liquid soap. So far I've connected the [Webcaster](https://github.com/webcast/webcaster) demo to the liquidsoap server running with the following command `liquidsoap "output.ao(fallible=true,audio_to_stereo(input.harbor('mount',port=8080)))"`

Now I want to connect liquidsoap to an Icecast server and get an URL in order to listen the streaming.

I've read the documentation of liquidsoap and it shows the following example:

```
liquidsoap 
  'output.icecast(%vorbis,
     host = "localhost", port = 8000, \
     password = "hackme", mount = "liq.ogg", \
     mksafe(playlist("playlist.m3u")))'
```

I was able to get the streaming only with liquidsoap using `input.harbor`. How do I change it to send to Icecast? Do I need to create a configuration file?

In the liquidsoap's example it references a playlist.m3u and I want the livestream.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as script.liq and run `liquidsoap script.liq`

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap

# Log dir
set("log.file.path","/tmp/some-radio.log")

# Live DJ stuff
set("harbor.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")
set("harbor.verbose",true)
livedj = input.harbor(
       "mount",
       port=8080,
       password="hackme"
)

# If something goes wrong, we'll play this
#security = single("/home/osboxes/Documents/liquidsoap/error.mp3")

# Set Radio
radio = fallback(track_sensitive = false, [livedj])


# Stream it out
output.icecast(
        %mp3(bitrate=128),
        fallible=true,
        host = "localhost",
        port = 8000,
        password = "hackme",
        mount = "master",
        radio
)
```